# Eclipse Git "Commit Changes" missing file

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have this one single .java file which doesn't show up in the "Commit Changes" window. It shows the > symbol in the file view when I change and save it and it shows up in the Git Staging view as unstaged, but the commit window won't let me proceed since it thinks there are no files (it does show Files (1/1) though).

I am able to stage it and commit it manually from the Git Staging view or from the command line. I just cannot commit it from the Commit window.

[image]

Comment: You can commit it in the commit windows, but if you don't `add` the files first, there is nothing to commit

Comment: The file is added already. It's already been previously committed. After I further modify the file, the commit window alone is not listing the file, even though the rest of the system has detected the changes. If I undo the changes then it will say that there are no changes and won't show the commit window at all.